# Sublime Text 3 irregularly fails to save changes

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

Occasionally when I'm using ST3, it says it has saved my changes, but it has not.

Here's what I'm experiencing:

1. I'll be editing a file (usually html, css, or js)
2. Save my changes, switch to Chrome, refresh, examine changes
3. Go back to ST3, make more changes, save, and switch back to Chrome
4. Refresh, changes are not visible. Refresh, refresh, refresh, refresh, still can not see changes.
5. Go back to ST3, make substantive change to file, and save again.
6. Go back to Chrome, refresh again, changes are updated.

This happens frequently, maybe once or twice per hour of active coding.

When it's in the state of having made/saved changes, but them not appearing, (between step #4 and #5) it looks as if ST3 has not saved the file to disk. If I `cat` the file out in the terminal, my changes are not shown. This leads me to believe ST3 hasn't actually committed the changes to disk, and that the problem isn't with Chrome, or other elements of my process.

If anyone could offer solutions or further troubleshooting steps, I'd really appreciate it. This is starting to drive me bonkers. This has been going on a while, but I'm sorry to say I can not seem to reliably reproduce it. Thanks!

Comment: You can turn on some setting that turns your document title red (or any other color) when it has unsaved changes. That might help in the debugging. It might be a browser cache acting up, but that `cat` check is a mystery though :p.

Comment: Yes, by default ST has an unsaved indicator in the tab. 'x' button is saved, circle has unsaved changes. See example -> http://f.cl.ly/items/2G3U321q0c3H0d0P0c2G/Screen%20Shot%202014-02-20%20at%202.46.12%20PM.png

Comment: I meant the "highlight_modified_tabs" setting, but that also works (though mine seems to have those indicators off atm, (v3).